# How to use DropBox API in the android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I m developing application which is using the Dropbox API to get authentication.
now i want to use the Dropbox API to do the File operation but do not know how to do.
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need in here : https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on how to use dropbox API -- the example is in iPhone but it should be similar for Android.

http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/1/20/how-to-synchronize-your-app-data-using-dropbox-api.html